# How to authenticate keycloak token using node js that calls postgraphile?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, postgraphile

I'm new on node js, and the company that i work for needs a proof of concept about postgraphile, the situation is this:

1. I created a node js mini server that uses postgraphile to access the data on postgres
2. The mini server works fine and can return data and also can use mutations.
3. I used keycloak-connect to try to access keycloak to authenticate the token from the request that is sent by postman but there is a problem.
4. If the token is valid or not it does not matter for the mini server, the only thing that seems to matter is that is a bearer token.

I tried to use other plugins (like keycloak-nodejs-connect, keycloak-verify, etc) but the result is the same, i also changed my code to use the examples in the documentation of those plugins but nothing.

This is my code: (keycloak-config.js file)

```
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

let _keycloak;

var keycloakConfig = {
    clientId: 'type credential',
    bearerOnly: true,
    serverUrl: 'our company server',
    realm: 'the test realm',
    grantType: "client_credentials",
    credentials: {
        secret: 'our secret'
    }
};

function initKeycloak(){
    if(_keycloak){
        console.warn("Trying to init Keycloak again!");
        return _keycloak;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Initializing Keycloak...");
        var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
        _keycloak = new Keycloak({store: memoryStore}, keycloakConfig);

        return _keycloak;
    }
}

function getKeycloak(){
    if(!_keycloak){
        console.error('Keycloak has not been initialized. Please called init first');
    }

    return _keycloak;
}

module.exports = {
    initKeycloak,
    getKeycloak
};
```

My Index.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const postgraphile = require('./postgraphile')
const app = express()

const keycloak = require('../config/keycloak-config').initKeycloak()

var router = express.Router();

app.set( 'trust proxy', true );
app.use(keycloak.middleware());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(postgraphile);

app.get('/', keycloak.checkSso(), (req, res) => {
    res.send('success');
    } );

var server = app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${8080}`));
```

Also I used this code to get the token and use the keycloak-verify plugin but got nothing:

```
router.get('/',keycloak.protect(),function(req, res, next) {
    var token=req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log(token);

    try {
        let user = keycloak.jwt.verify(token);
        console.log(user.isExpired());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})
```

I know that I lack the knowledge because I am a backend (C#) developer, can somebody help me with this?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem:

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
var keycloakConfig = require('../AuthOnly/config/keycloak-config').keycloakConfig;
const postgraphile = require('./postgraphile');

const app = express();

const keycloakHost = keycloakConfig.serverUrl;
const realmName = keycloakConfig.realm;

// check each request for a valid bearer token
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // assumes bearer token is passed as an authorization header
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    // configure the request to your keycloak server
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${keycloakHost}/auth/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo`,
      headers: {
        // add the token you received to the userinfo request, sent to keycloak
        Authorization: req.headers.authorization,
      },
    };

    // send a request to the userinfo endpoint on keycloak
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      // if the request status isn't "OK", the token is invalid
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        res.status(401).json({
          error: `unauthorized`,
        });
      }
      // the token is valid pass request onto your next function
      else {
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    // there is no token, don't process request further
    res.status(401).json({
    error: `unauthorized`,
  });
}});

app.use(postgraphile);

app.listen(8080);
```